# My users can upload images, should each user have a folder for his images or should I just store all images in 1 folder?

Tags: php, laravel, storage

Currently, I have a folder uploads which constains folders like images, albums and tags. Whenever a user uploads an image, I put it the the images folder and the folder contains images from all users. Would it be better if I change so that I have folder "users" that contains their uploaded images?

Comment: Yes. No. Maybe! (Seriously, that's the answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine to store all images in one folder.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I was wondering if there's a certain standard to uphold.